# 8-9 digits latitude/longitude format

Tags: latitude-longitude

i have a database of latitude and longitude GPS coordinates in this format:

```
Latidude                        Longitude
```

`20908403.7226004675030708        223749828.7524890005588531`

`20908403.7325199767947197        223749828.7432585060596466`

`20908403.2405762746930122        223749828.7983648478984833`

I tried to do a 1/10^6 rescaling and the trajectory i obtained is the expected one, but i'm struggling too understand the format of the coordinates and their physical meaning.

In my opinion those cannot be:

- decimal degrees: 52.145339, 5.331997;
- NE coordinates: 52°08'43.2"N 5°19'55.2"E;
- Some kind of ECEF-like coordinates;

and i'm out of options.

Thank you in advance for your help,
greetings.

Alessandro

#### Update:

The format was a "proprietary" one by the company we were working for.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, this format is to "increase" the accuracy with more decimal digits. But, it is important to know the following:
[be careful with the number of digits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRK08.png)

Comment: Yeah, i agree with you but still do not understand the format of those coordinates.

Comment: I agree on the impossible precision. Most probably there's a conversion to do and those are not even proper coordinates in this form.
It is interesting thou the fact that from an incremental point of view those numbers, treated as coordinates and projected on the local cartesian reference system, produce the correct trajectory i'm expecting knwing the measured track.